# Google Apps Script - Returning data results based on multiple criteria

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to run a script that validates a table of stagnant data against several criteria.
I am fairly new to using scripts, and I spent most of yesterday gaining a base knowledge but I am still struggling.
The first objective I want to achieve is checking dates - I want to check the dates in one column, row by row, and if any of the dates are greater than the corresponding date two columns over I want either the whole row or just the second column value to return when I run the script. I think my main problem is that I still cannot fully grasp how to use the return function. So far I am only able to return the whole data set, not just the results of my if statement.

```
function dateValidation() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var cell = sheet.getRange(1,21,5000,1) //first date column
var cell2 = sheet.getRange (1,23,5000,1) //second date column
var cell3 = sheet.getRange (1,2,5000,1) //column to return
  for(var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
    if(cell.getValues() > cell2.getValues())
    return cell3.getValues(); 
}
```

I have a feeling I may be going about this all wrong with the if statement. I typically use formulas like extended queries but for this, I need a function to adhere to a button to be able to validate the data on a whim, not have it constantly update in a query. Any help would be greatly appreciated, but I know I still have a lot to learn.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

**I tried to replicate your code and found some issues.**

1. using `values.length` in your for loop might introduce index out of bounds once the number of rows in your `values`is not the same with the number of rows indicated in the 3rd parameter of `getRange(1,21,5000,1)`.
2. The return of getValues() is 2 dimensional array. You have to indicate index of array you want to check to be able to access the data inside the array.
3. Using `return cell3.getValues();` statement inside `for loop` will just return the whole values of cell3 once the condition is met.

**To fix the issues:**

1. Use `values.length` as third parameter of `cell,cell2,cell3` `getRange()`.
2. Each Array inside the 2d array represents a rows of data. Since we only need 1 column for `cell`, `cell2`, and `cell3` we can indicate `array[i][0]` to access the first element of each array.
3. Instead of using `return`, create a empty array above the for loop and use `push()` to store the data that matches the condition.

**Example:**

[image: Sample]

**Code:**

```
function dateValidation() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var cell = sheet.getRange(1,1,values.length,1).getValues(); //first date column
  var cell2 = sheet.getRange (1,2,values.length,1).getValues(); //second date column
  var cell3 = sheet.getRange (1,3,values.length,1).getValues(); //column to return
  var single_col = [];
  var whole_row = [];
  for(var i = 1; i < cell.length; i++) {
    if(cell[i][0] > cell2[i][0])
    {
      single_col.push(cell3[i][0]);
      whole_row.push(values[i]);
    }
  }
  Logger.log(single_col);
  Logger.log(whole_row);
  //choose either of these two below.
  //return single_col;
  //return whole_row;
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

### References:

[Javascript Return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)

[getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)

[getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)

[Array.prototype.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)